# What log message an event generates to blockchain?

Tags: solidity

The following is a portion of a `Ballot.sol`. There is a `event votingCompleted()` defined and triggered in `function vote`. What is the detail message this `votingCompleted` is going to emit to blockchain?

I understand `event` could serve log but what is the log message looks like? The `event` code itself did not provide any details about what log it will emit when triggered.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract Ballot {

 ....

    event votingCompleted();

    uint startTime;
    modifier validStage(Stage reqStage) {
        require(stage == reqStage);
        _;
    }

    constructor(uint8 _numProposals) public {
        chairperson = msg.sender;
        voters[chairperson].weight = 2;
        proposals.length = _numProposals;
        stage = Stage.Reg;
        startTime = now;
    }

    function vote(uint8 toProposal) public validStage(Stage.Vote) {
        Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
        if (sender.voted || toProposal >= proposals.length) return;
        sender.voted = true;
        sender.vote = toProposal;
        proposals[toProposal].voteCount += sender.weight;
        if (now > (startTime + 30 seconds)) {
            stage = Stage.Done;
            emit votingCompleted();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the event log emitted would simply be the topic `0x6ac0c89219f0135e3a87cecdf1851abced71da933a0a00e1eada0ef035382351`, which is `keccak256("votingCompleted()")`

This event has no data or indexed parameters, so it's just a single topic, which will be included in the block's bloom filers.

A better example of to explain how events work would be to look at the `Transfer(address,address,uint256)` event from the ERC20 standard. If we look at a [random BAT transfer](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcfe3438e9bbf0c9b412ac20864ecab26647270a6b7694222cf4c755ea1cce1c5), we see the event log as:

```
Transfer (index_topic_1 address _from, index_topic_2 address _to, uint256 _value)
Topics  [0] 0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef
        [1] 0x0000000000000000000000009c808cd59d94a07053658b00ea12d8e9cbbe8304
        [2] 0x0000000000000000000000002f93a4798539a055e63d77e7cef9cc99302cbe50
Data    0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000086bd25ccc0d0b8a43
```

(this is etherscan's parsed view, but it conveys the point).

Here, we can see three topics. The first is `keccak256("Transfer(address,address,uint256)")`, which tells us what the event was. The second and third are the addresses of the sender and recipient respectively. These are indexed, and hence are topics instead of data fields. Being indexed, they will also be included in the bloom filter, and filter queries can be used to find them.

The last bit is the data, which is not indexed. This represents the amount of tokens moved, but cannot be looked up through a filter query.